# Multilayer WCF duplex communication

Tags: c#, wcf, message-passing, duplex

I have this problem. I have two WCF services - `ServiceA` and `ServiceB`. Both services are host in different windows services and communicate via net.tcp. Client access `Service A`. In `Service A` I access `Service B`. Problem what I got is that I want to communication be duplex.

That is I want client to call method `TestA` in `ServiceA`. This method would call method `TestB` in `ServiceB`. Method `TestB` would make some long duration action and then raises callback back to `ServiceA` that would raises callback to client. Methods `TestA`and `TestB`are one way contracts.

[image: communication schema]

I can get to the point in which `ServiceA` raises callback back to client. Then it crashes on InvalidCastException trying to get callback channel in operation context.

```
IServiceACallback Callback
    {
        get
        {
            return OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceACallback>();
        }
    }
```

Is it because I am in a different thread and operation context is just simply not complete? Because I can raise callback back to client when I am not doing it from another callback from `ServiceB`. Can I solve it with some service attributes maybe? Or is there some communication pattern that I can use?

Comment: The architecture should work.  Exception like yours usually occurs when you get partial messages.  Make sure the receiving code clearly knows the end of each message.  Trying to read more data than exists in the input buffer will cause under-flows and create exceptions.

Comment: Do you mean invalidCastException?

Comment: Yes, it is InvalidCastException

Comment: It must have something to do with OperationContext lifecycle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out.

By raising callback from `ServiceB` to `ServiceA` I was in different OperationContext. This context was on entirely different thread so got no connection with the `Client` but instead got part of OperationContext from `ServiceB`.

I added new member to CallbackHandler of `ServiceA` that points to OperationContext. To this I pass current context during creation of `ServiceB` using `DuplexChannelfactory`. This context is the correct one and can be used to raises callbacks back to `Client`. I hope that code makes it understandable.

Creation of `ServiceB` in `ServiceA`:

```
InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(new CallbackHandler(OperationContext.Current));
ChannelFactory<IService> factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceB>(context, binding, address);
IServiceB service = factory.CreateChannel();
```

CallbackHandler of `ServiceA`:

```
public class CallbackHandler : IServiceBCallback
{
    OperationContext _context;

    public CallbackHandler(OperationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void TestProgress(string msg)
    {
        IServiceACallback callback = _context.GetCallbackChannel<IServiceACallback>();
        callback.TestProgress(msg);
    }
}
```